# Pysvn:propset() shows Path does not exist in revision 0 Error

Tags: python, pysvn

python script,

```
   root = "..."

   commit_info = svncl.propset( "myprop",
                                "Test",                                       
                                root,
                                revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head))
```

shows Error,
**pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError: Path "..." does not exist in revision 0.**

Comment: Can anyone pls give an idea to solve this Error...

Comment: Is "..." a valid path here? I would expect not. Second, are there any commits in this repository? Try using "." as the path instead.

Comment: Hi Corley "..." is a valid path only. There are 65 revisions in the Repository. Try using "." -> what it mean ? Can u pls...

Comment: Corley "..."(https://localhost/svn/Test_Repos/Test1) is a valid path only and able to set the property by using TortoiseSVN and svn.exe. There are 65 revisions in the Repository.

Comment: Two things strike me here: first, the head revision is being set to 0, which would lead me to believe that the path is incorrect in some way. Second, the URL you have given has the https protocol. Have you set up correct authentication? Note that PySVN (usually) doesn't error on incorrect login information. It may also be worth trying to use svn:// instead of https://. (Also, a path of just "." means the current directory the script is being ran in.)

Comment: I'm having the similar error... any news here? I am getting `Path https://myserver.com/svnrepo/prj1 does not exist in revision 0` even though I set `revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head)`. I just did branching and other command via pysvn, but propset gives this error. Any idea?

Comment: @Danijel See my answer :)

Comment: @user1553605 Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set base_revision_for_url:

```python
commit_info = svncl.propset(
    "myprop", "Test", root,
    base_revision_for_url=svncl.revpropget("revision", root)[0].number
)
```

See this bug report for reference: http://pysvn.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=146

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'revision'`. Any idea? Documentation says: `base_revision_for_url=[0 for URL, -1 for path]`

Comment: Great, works. I am unclear what to set for `revision` argument? For now I skip it: `info = client.propset('svn:externals', dest_externals, dest_externals_url, base_revision_for_url=client.revpropget("revision", dest_externals_url)[0].number)`

Comment: I think that's fine. I also don't set it and it's working.